# Why does window.onload ignore postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Consider the following js code (to click an asp.net `Button` on load):

```
function doSomething()
{
    document.getElementById("<%= theButton.ClientID %>").click();
}
window.onload = doSomething;
```

When the page is loaded - the codebehind of the button is executed, and the page is loaded again (with new information). This *should* have introduced a bug of an infinite loop, but it doesn't. It is only called once, and ignored in the postback.

Why?

Comment: how does the page reloads ?? what do you mean by this

Comment: Why don't you use the `_doPostBack()` method from Javascript?

Comment: @EkanshRastogi It's an asp.net thing - when codebehind is executed - the page gets a [postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback).

Comment: Does the page postback when you click the button manually?

Comment: @Ian Yes, if I remove the js, and click the button - there's a postback.

Comment: @LcSalazar Looks interesting. I need to look into that.

Comment: @ispiro Have you considered using `document.onload`? Of course the browser's window will only be loaded once

Comment: @MatiCicero [It doesn't look like that would make a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload). But anyway - I want to know if I can rely on this not creating an infinite loop, or whether I need to somehow confirm it isn't a postback before firing.

Comment: @ispiro if you need to confirm it isn't a postback before clicking the button, why not just use `!Page.IsPostBack` to determine whether to execute that code?

Comment: Is it possible that your browser somehow prevents the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `doSomething` method to be called only the first time the page loads:

You should add your call to `doSomething` to the page using `Page.RegisterStartupScript` in the code behind, but wrap it in an if statement that checks if it is a postback. That way, your method will only be called the first time the page loads:

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "buttonClickScript" "window.onload = doSomething;", true);
 }
```

Comment: He asks why there is no infinite loop not how to fix it.

Comment: I was basing this on the OPs comment: "I want to know if I can rely on this not creating an infinite loop". Doing it this way, you don't need to rely on it not creating an infinite loop. I would imagine the behaviour described is because the OPs script is executed before the asp.net generated _postback script is loaded and attached to the button. I wouldnt rely on it, I would control the page flow form the server side code.